# Function $\sqrt[5]{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram alpha tell me that $\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x}}{x}$ does not exists and in particular the domain of $\sqrt[5]{x}$ is given by all $x\geq 0$...why? I should say that $\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x}}{x}=+\infty$ and the domain is all $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Well, $\;\cfrac{\sqrt[5]x}x=\cfrac1{x^{4/5}}\;$ and the domain is $\;\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\;$ .

Comment: $+\infty$ is not a real number, hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: I am referring to the domain of $\sqrt[5]{x}$

Comment: The domain of $\sqrt[5] x$ is actually $\mathbb R$.

Comment: But wolfram alpha tell me only $x\geq 0$ and tell me that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{x}}{x}$ does not exists...I don't understand

Comment: @player3236 That is a matter of convention. If the limit is $\;+\infty\;$ then it certainly can be said it exists, but not finitely.

Comment: Wolfram is taking $\sqrt[5]{-1}\approx-0.81-0.59i$, I think that is the [problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22limit%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22FP%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22direction%22%7D+-%3E+%22Left%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22limitfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22x%5E%281%2F5%29%2Fx%22)

Comment: @Nik Wolframalpha must be high, as many...really many...other times. It is not the absolute truth and it has quite a few bugs which give false results. It can be an excellent tool...but it must be taken with proper care.

Comment: Ok thanks so it is right to say that $\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x}}{x}=+\infty$?

Comment: @Nik Yes indeed, as that's the answer. Now, whether that is considered as "the limit exists" is, as already commented, a matter of convention...but I'd say we could at least say the limit existsin a generalized way.

Comment: @DonAntonio Okok thanks a lot!

Comment: I suppose that you would have the same problem with $\sqrt[3]x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x^{1/5}$, Wolfram|Alpha will take the [principal root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%281%2F5%29) by default but you can 'force' it to take the [real-valued root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%281%2F5%29&assumption=%22%5E%22%20-%3E%20%22Real%22) instead: it then correctly reports the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$.

The same goes for the limit you are trying to calculate: [principal (default)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x%5E%281%2F5%29%2Fx%2C%20x%20to%200-) vs. [real-valued](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x%5E%281%2F5%29%2Fx%2C%20x%20to%200-&assumption=%22%5E%22%20-%3E%20%22Real%22) with the correct result:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x}}{x}=+\infty$$

I think it mainly illustrates how you should be *very careful* with interpreting what mathematical computer software tells you.

See also: [Principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value).

Comment: Thank you very mouch!

Answer (score 0):

Extending StackTD's answer, the first thing to notice is that in the expression below, since $x$ is approaching $0$ **from below**, both the numerator and the denominator will be negative.  Therefore, the fraction is positive.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x}}{x}.$$

For simplicity, you can therefore convert the problem to evaluating:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x}}{x}.$$

At this point there are three ways to complete the evaluation, two formal and one informal:

1. divide both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt[5]{x}$, which converts the fraction to $\frac{1}{x^{(4/5)}}.$  Here, since the denominator is approaching $0$ **from above**, the fraction is clearly going to $+\infty.$
2. Apply L'Hopital's Rule, which transforms the fraction into
   $\frac{[1/5]x^{(-4/5)}}{1}$, which, as in the first approach, clearly evaluates to $+\infty.$
3. Rely solely on intuition.  Consider what happens as $x$ progressively takes on the values $0.9, 0.8, 0.7, ...$ so that $x^2$ is simultaneously taking on the values $0.81, 0.64, 0.49, ...$.  Clearly as $x$ goes to $0^+$, $x^2$ goes to $0^+$ **more quickly** (told you this was **informal**).  Therefore, as $x$ goes to $0^+, \sqrt[5]{x}$ goes to $0^+$ **more slowly**.  This insight permits you to reach the accurate conclusion **without** (much) math.